# Retrieving multiple last rows of occurences of a column based on same first column

Tags: shell

I have the following file:

```
 ABC 1234 2333 BCD
 ABC  121  123 BCD
 ABC  124  231 BCD
 ABC 2342 2344 CDK
 MBN  231   252  RFC
 MBN  230   212  RFC
 MBN  213   215  RFC
 MBN  233   235  RFC
 MBN  12   67  RTC
 MBN  67   98  TCF
```

I want to find the last row of unique first and fourth column value based on search from another file, my other file will have

```
  ABC 
  MBN
```

The code will work such that it will look for ABC first in the above file, then find last occurrence of BCD and so on and the output would be:

```
  ABC  124  231 BCD
  ABC 2342 2344 CDK  
  MBN  233   235  RFC 
  MBN  67   98  TCF
```

I have begun by first finding the occurrence of ABC as

```
grep ABC abovefile.txt | head -1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{search[$1];next} $1 in search{key=$1 SEP $4; if (!(key in data)) c[++n]=key;
   data[key]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print data[c[i]]}' file2 file1
```

**Output:**

```
ABC  124  231 BCD
ABC 2342 2344 CDK
MBN  233   235  RFC
MBN  12   67  RTC
MBN  67   98  TCF
```

This solution is using 3 arrays:

- `search` to hold search items from `file2`
- `data` to hold records from `file1` with the key as `$1,$4`
- `c` for keeping the order of the already processed keys

**Code Breakup:**

```
NR==FNR           # Execute next block for the 1st file in the list (i.e. file2)
{search[$1];next} # store first column in search array and move to next record
$1 in search      # for next file in the list if first col exists in search array
key=$1 SEP $4     # make key variable as $1, $4
if(!(key in data))# if key is not in data array
c[++n]=key        # store in array c with an incrementing index
data[key]=$0}     # not store full record in data array with index=key
END               # run this block at the end
```

Comment: Works great, except if it would not be too much can you break the code ?

Comment: Oh sorry I did plus one to it,will click it, also what if I have to find out the unique last one in the same file irrespective of a search file?

Comment: In that case `awk '{key=$1 SEP $4; if (!(key in data)) c[++n]=key; data[key]=$0} END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print data[c[i]]}' file1` would work.

Comment: Hi I have one more question on this code, why would it store the last value of the keys ,I would assume that since if we use unique key ($4 makes a difference), each row with same first column but different 4 th column will be stored at different indices right?

Comment: If you want first unique record then use: `awk 'NR==FNR{search[$1];next} $1 in search{key=$1 SEP $4; if (!(key in data)) {c[++n]=key; data[key]=$0}} END{for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print data[c[i]]}' file2 file1`  Since we were already overwriting `data` array that's why we had only last entry.

Comment: So the only difference would be a bracket and no bracket for the statement c[++n]=key; data[key]=$0?How would that make a difference?

Comment: Due to placement of bracket now `data[key]=$0` runs only when `if (!(key in data))` condition is `true` which will only return true for the first record.

Comment: `Effective awk Programming, 4th Edition` by Arnold Robbins or online: https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf